# How to increase mat-option cell size

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I want toget style similiar to one shown in pic when I hover over the mat-option.

[image]

To achieve this I need to move other mat-option element move little low, how to do this, currently I am able to style on hovering mat-option elements.

My question is to how to display a text similiar to shown in pic on hovering over mat-option? You can see in pic it is not styled properly.

This is my css class

```
.mat-option:hover{
  background-color:#D6CDC9 !important;
  font-family:ffunit;
  color: black;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight: bold;

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just increased styled length attribute,this worked

```
.mat-option:hover{
  background-color:white !important;
  font-family:ffunit;
  color: black;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height:35%;

}
```